# How to map specific date into an Elasticsearch date/time field?

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, mapping

I have used many different ways to convert the date/time below into an ES date format:

```
Thu Oct 29 08:17:25 2015
```

The format I use for a date like `2012-12-12 12:12:12` is as below

```
"properties":{
   "my_date_field":{
   "type":"date",
   "format":"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"
 }
}
```

I went through [the documentation of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html), but there was not a format I need to turn `Thu Oct 29 08:17:25 2015` into Elasticsearch `date/time` field. In what way should I convert it? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    "date": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy||EEE MMM  dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei, it works on some fields but not others! Some of the fields are like: `Wed Apr  6 10:55:41 2016`

Comment: Isn't there a way to make day part flexible between single number (2,3,...) and 12,23,....?

Comment: Hm, you sure? I just tested `Wed Apr 6 10:55:41 2016` and it was indexed without issues.

Comment: It is  `Wed Apr  6 10:55:41 2016`. There is 2 spaces between `Apr` and `6`! Extra space is removed in comment.

Comment: Then you can go with `"format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy||EEE MMM  dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"` but that's not actually how it's supposed to be fixed. If you are sure you will only have one space or two in there, then you should be ok, but if the number of spaces is variable you need to fix this on the client side, at indexing time.

Comment: It is a server side issue and needs to be fixed, but thanks for the workaround I will use it for now. +1

Comment: My comment seems to have ignored the double spaces I added. I edited the response with the double spaces and it seems it was kept as I wanted it to be.